# Two pages of website scrolling sideways. Other pages fine

Tags: horizontal-scrolling

I have two pages on my website making the user scroll sideways while other pages on the site are fine. All other pages are fine, so I can only think it's the banner image halfway down that's causing it (if you scroll to the right, all you get is whitespace). I'm thinking maybe I have an extra DIV in there or something but it validates. Anyone able to look at it with fresh eyes? Thanks in advance!

Validated code and tried resizing the image percentage but that isn't fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can press `F12` in your chrome window and the use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + C` which will enable 'Hover element to inspect it', when you hover over an element now, the element's dimensions should be visible.

You can use this information to find out exactly which part of your website is causing the side scrolling (I'd imagine its some extra margin or transparent padding somewhere but it's impossible to tell without looking at the code)

Give that a go, see if you can find exactly what's causing the issue and if you still don't understand how to solve your issue once you've found the breaking code we can work from there :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. So I think it's my navbar. I see it causing some overflow, but it isn't causing problems on any other page. One of the two pages in question is https://www.nickigreenwood.com/books/excerpts/tfre.html. Source code is https://www.nickigreenwood.com/style.css.